# Spring Batch Using Reactor - Adapting Flux to a Queue Possible Alternatives

Tags: spring, project-reactor, blocking

I'm currently implementing a Spring Batch application that subscribes to a Reactor Flux to read an encrypted fixed format file, line by line. The Flux emits lines as Java Records.

The Spring Batch ItemReader I'm creating needs to implement a method that blocks until it emits the next item from the flux, so I need to adapt from the Reactive pattern to the blocking pattern.

My current solution is to:

1. Subscribe to the flux which emits items into a BlockingQueue.
2. Pull items from that queue.

However, I had to implement this thing, and I'm wondering if there is some hidden magic in Reactor that would do this in a couple lines?

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

/**
 * A class that subscribes to a Flux then allows polling from that publisher's output, buffered
 * into a queue.
 *
 * @param <T> The type of items provided.
 */
public class QueueSubscriber<T> {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueueSubscriber.class);
  public static final int DEFAULT_QUEUE_SIZE = 10;

  final BlockingQueue<T> itemQueue;

  final AtomicReference<Throwable> subscriptionError = new AtomicReference<>();
  final AtomicBoolean lastItemSubmitted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
  final AtomicBoolean isSubscribed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  final Duration pollTimeout;

  Flux<T> flux;

  /**
   *
   * @param flux The flux to subscribe to on the first call to take()
   */
  public QueueSubscriber(Flux<T> flux) {
    this.flux = flux;
    this.itemQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(DEFAULT_QUEUE_SIZE);
    this.pollTimeout = Duration.ofMillis(1);
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param flux The flux to subscribe to on the first call to take()
   * @param subscribeNow Whether to subscribe now, or if false, subscribe on the first call of take()
   */
  public QueueSubscriber(Flux<T> flux, boolean subscribeNow) {
    this.flux = flux;
    this.itemQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(DEFAULT_QUEUE_SIZE);
    this.pollTimeout  = Duration.ofMillis(1);

    if (subscribeNow) {
      subscribe();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Block until we can get the next item emitted by the flux.
   *
   * @return The next item from the queue or null if we have reached the end of the flux.
   */
  public T take() {
    // Start the subscription if we haven't already.
    subscribe();

    // Check for any errors emitted by the subscription.
    Throwable subscriptionError = this.subscriptionError.get();
    if (subscriptionError != null) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error during subscription to flux.",
          this.subscriptionError.get());
    }

      T item = null;
      while (item == null) {
        switch (state()) {
          // Keep trying to poll items until we get one. Waiting a maximum of 2 milliseconds for the next item
          case SUB_NOT_FINISHED, QUEUE_HAS_ITEMS_SUB_FINISHED:
            item = poll();
            continue;

          // Last item is null.
          case FINISHED:
            return null;
        };
      }

      // Return the next item.
      return item;
  }

  /**
   * Poll for a time period of this.pollTimeout() and return the result.
   * @return The next item in the queue or null if there isn't one yet.
   */
  private T poll() {
    try {
      if(pollTimeout != null) {
        return itemQueue.poll(pollTimeout.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      } else {
        return itemQueue.poll();
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(
          "Interrupted while waiting for next item in queue.");
    }
  }

  private State state() {
    if (lastItemSubmitted.get()) {
      if (itemQueue.isEmpty()) {
        return State.FINISHED;
      } else {
        return State.QUEUE_HAS_ITEMS_SUB_FINISHED;
      }
    } else {
      return State.SUB_NOT_FINISHED;
    }
  }

  private void subscribe() {
    if(isSubscribed.getAndSet(true)) {
      // Do not subscribe a second time.
      return;
    }

    // Start streaming lines from the file into our queue for processing at leisure. Stopping items when the queue is full.
    flux
        .doOnError(this::subscriptionError)
        .doOnCancel(() -> this.subscriptionError(new RuntimeException(
            "Subscription to flux cancelled.")))
        .doOnComplete(() -> this.lastItemSubmitted.set(true))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .subscribe(nextItem -> {
          try {
            // Will wait to put items until the queue has space.
            itemQueue.put(nextItem);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Thread was interrupted while waiting for the queue to accept the next line.",
                e);
          }
        });

    LOG.debug("Subscribed to flux.");
  }

  /**
   * When an error occurs during the read process then add it to the proxi
   *
   * @param error The error that occurred in the subscription.
   */
  private void subscriptionError(Throwable error) {
    this.subscriptionError.getAndUpdate(t -> {
      if (t == null) {
        return error;
      } else {
        // This shouldn't happen unless the flux resumes after an exception.
        LOG.error("Second error occurred while subscribing to file flux.",
            t);
        return t;
      }
    });
  }

  private enum State {
    /**
     * The subscription has not finished submitting items to the queue.
     */
    SUB_NOT_FINISHED,
    /**
     * The subscription has finished submitting items to the queue, and they have all been taken.
     */
    FINISHED,
    /**
     * The subscription has finished but there are still items on the queue.
     */
    QUEUE_HAS_ITEMS_SUB_FINISHED
  }
}
```

I've already implemented this method, but it's not exactly the best. I'm kind of hoping Reactor will have some method similar to this that people have spent more than a few hours testing and setting up. Unfortunately my Google Fu has failed me.

Comment: Reactor and Spring Batch aren't a good fit as flux is more for stream processing then batch processing. You are only adding complexity to move from one to the other, just utilize the regular means of reading a file instead of trying to shoehorn this into a Flux which you need to shoehorn into Spring Batch later on.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Deinum! Yeah, I wish that was possible, however the rest of my application is using WebFlux. Spring Batch is just the "Odd man out." After a few tweaks, this adaptation seems to be working okay, I'm just a little disappointed.

Comment: Then why use Spring Batch in the first place? You can just use stream processing with a flux and call map for the processing. Adding Spring Batch is more or less adding complexity then.

Comment: Hi Deinum! I've done what you are talking about in the past, however batch processing is a bit more complicated than that. For instance, what happens when your database goes down for ten minutes half way through a batch job? The complexity only goes up from there with regards to transaction management. Spring Batch allows you to abstract a lot of that away.

Comment: Trust me I know what Spring Batch does, but it doesn't match very well with stream processing (which is what you are doing more or less). I had a discussion about this with Michael Minella (former Spring Batch lead) a couple of years ago already. Here you are complicating it additionally with trying to be non-blocking but in a blocking way. I'm not saying you cannot make it work but you are combining 2 paradigms (maybe even 3) which aren't really meant to be combined (which is what you see in the complexity of trying to bridge those worlds).,

Comment: I think you're right. I'm not seeing much value added by Spring Batch for this. I'll probably pivot to just a plain Spring Boot application without the batch stuff.